# Unable to inject service in bean shell script or call a service method in bean shell

Tags: java, beanshell

for example:

i enter java code in textarea:

```
package com.test.webapp.controller;
import org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity
import com.test.webapp.controller;
import java.util.HashMap;


HashMap message = new HashMap();
message.put("table","TEST");
message.put("ID","1236");
message.put("NAME","Three");
message.put("AREA","chennai");
JavaTest javaTest = new JavaTest();
javaTest.saveMessage(message);
```

i receive the above code as string named "javaEvent" in my java controller

```
public @ResponseBody void executeJavaCode(@RequestParam("javaEvent") String javaEvent) {
    Interpreter interpreter = new Interpreter();  
    interpreter.eval(javaEvent);
}




public void saveMessage( Map<String, String> tableDetails) {
    System.out.println("===============mess============="+message.size());
    }
```

saveMessage method in java code gets executed fine.. 
but calling any service method in saveMessage throws null pointer exception. service is not injected here .. 
how to call service method in bean scripts??

for example : (like this i need)

```
public void saveMessage( Map<String, String> tableDetails) {
    System.out.println("===============mess============="+message.size());
    testService.someMethod(tableDetails);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

How are are you expecting the instance of JavaTest or the HashMap to be accessible in the service instance after calling? After the script evaluates, those objects are eligible for GC, unless JavaTest is setting some static variable?

If you wish to hold the reference after the script evaluates then consider passing the variable into the script:

```
public @ResponseBody void executeJavaCode(@RequestParam("javaEvent") 
       String javaEvent) {
    Interpreter interpreter = new Interpreter();  
    message = new HashMap();
    interpreter.set("message", message); 
    interpreter.eval(javaEvent);
    // do stuff to message
}
```

Alternatively, you could also return the variable from your script.

Comment: thanks for your reply.. the instance of javaTest is calling the saveMessage method correctly.. but i am unable to use any service in saveMessage method. For example i would like to pass the map details to other service like                                                             public void saveMessage( Map<String, String> tableDetails) {
    System.out.println("===============mess============="+message.size());
    testService.someMethod(tableDetails);

    }